# What is the difference between log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size and log.cleaner.io.buffer.size?

Tags: apache-kafka

What is the difference between `log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size` and `log.cleaner.io.buffer.size`? What factors should be taken into account when configuring these values?

Comment: For starters, total memory on the machine should be taken into account... Cant set the buffer greater than the JVM heap. Then, if you aren't using compacted topics, then the dedupe buffer isn't really applicable

Comment: I am using compacted topics that is why I wanted to understand the significance of these two buffers.

Comment: I could be wrong, but only the dedupe one is for compaction and the other is for the whole log cleaner... I'm not finding documentation on it, and so the source code would likely need reviewed

Comment: log.cleaner.io.buffer.size controls total memory used for log cleaner I/O buffers across all cleaner threads and log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size specifies memory used for log compaction across all cleaner threads. I think log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size buffer used for offset mapping and detecting duplicate keys between clean and dirty messages
https://docs.cloudera.com/runtime/7.1.0/kafka-performance-tuning/topics/kafka-tune-broker-tuning-log-cleaner.html

Comment: @xabhi hello! were you able to find the difference? can you please provide your answer?